# How to compile a specific .spec.ts file in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I have an application with many components and spec files. Can I just compile a specific spec.ts files during the execution of `ng test` command?

My issue is that there are many syntax errors in the other `spec.ts` component files, so I am not able to run the test cases for a specific test file.

I tried prefixing the `describe` function name with `f`:

`fdescribe` and `fit` causes only functions marked this way to run, as there are still errors in the other spec file. The compiler throws error on the cmd and on the browser shows this message

```
KARMA V 6.3.9 - Connected;test:complete;

Incomplete: no specs found, , randomized with seed 1234
```

I even tried `ng test --include *path to the spec file*`, but this also throws same error as above.

How can I execute only specific `spec.ts` in the application?

Answer (score 2):

In `test.ts`, you can try changing this Regex to be more specific to the unit tests you would like to run. The Regex is the third argument. Be sure to change it back too.

```
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```